# "ADO NET Destination" (2) failed with error code 0xC020844B while processing input "ADO NET Destination Input" (9). ERROR

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio, ssis, ado

I have created an SSIS package. I created a table in SSMS and then linked it to the package.

However I later renamed the table created to convert it to a fact table. I had CustomerID set as a primary key.

I remapped all the required mappings but I am getting this error at the destination.

---

Old table name TblCustomer
Renamed to FactCustomer

> [SSIS.Pipeline] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PROCESSINPUTFAILED.  The ProcessInput method on component "ADO NET Destination" (2) failed with error code 0xC020844B while processing input "ADO NET Destination Input" (9). The identified component returned an error from the ProcessInput method. The error is specific to the component, but the error is fatal and will cause the Data Flow task to stop running.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.
>
> [ADO NET Destination [2]] Error: An exception has occurred during data insertion, the message returned from the provider is: Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_TblCustomer'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.FactCustomer'. The duplicate key value is (1001).
>   The statement has been terminated.

Comment: You've probably already checked this, but have you verified if any duplicate rows were sent to the ADO.NET Destination?

Answer (score 0):

The main error is:

> Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_TblCustomer'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.FactCustomer'. The duplicate key value is (1001)

Which is mean that you are inserting duplicates values into the Fact table, check that the data does not exists or the data doesn't contains duplicates.